# Annotate Total Created, Modified, and Deleted for each year

Tags: django, django-models

Given a Model `Item` how would I find the total number of items created, modified, and deleted every year? And can this be done in a single database query?

```
from django.db import models

class Item(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    modified_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    deleted_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

My current query returns the same counts for total_created, total_modified, and total_deleted.

```
from django.db.models.functions import ExtractYear

Item.objects.annotate(
    created_at_year=ExtractYear("created_at"),
    modified_at_year=ExtractYear("modified_at"),
    deleted_at_year=ExtractYear("deleted_at"),
).values("created_at_year", "modified_at_year", "deleted_at_year").annotate(
    total_created=models.Count("id"),
    total_modified=models.Count("id"),
    total_deleted=models.Count("id"),
)
```

Example Data

| id | created_at | modified_at | deleted_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 01:01:01 | 2020-01-01 01:01:01 | 2021-01-01 01:01:01 |
| 2 | 2020-01-01 01:01:01 | 2021-01-01 01:01:01 | 2021-01-01 01:01:01 |
| 3 | 2020-01-01 01:01:01 | 2021-01-01 01:01:01 | 2022-01-01 01:01:01 |

Desired Output

```
{
    2020: {"total_created": 3, "total_modified": 1, "total_deleted": 0},
    2021: {"total_created": 0, "total_modified": 2, "total_deleted": 2},
    2022: {"total_created": 0, "total_modified": 0, "total_deleted": 1},
}
```

I know it's possible to add `filter` parameter to `Count` but I do not know if I can use that here.

Comment: Can you give an example of your desired output? With a very minimal input if possible

Comment: @IainShelvington I switched the question to go by `year` and have added example data and desired output